# LEFT JOIN 3 columns to get username

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have three columns I need to join which comes from 3 different tables,

**Contributions table:**

```
+-----------+---------------------+
| record_id | contributor_user_id |
+-----------+---------------------+
|         1 |                   2 |
+-----------+---------------------+
|         1 |                   5 |
+-----------+---------------------+
```

**Members table:**

```
+--------------+---------+
| username     | user_id |
+--------------+---------+
| Test         |       1 |
+--------------+---------+
| Test2        |       5 |
+--------------+---------+
| Test3        |       6 |
+--------------+---------+
```

**Records table:**

```
+---------+-----------+
| user_id | record_id |
+---------+-----------+
|      28 |         1 |
+---------+-----------+
```

For what I need to return is the `username` and `user_id` for displaying the record owner. Also, display the `username` and the `user_id`, but this can be multiple (more than 1+ user). I've tried this:

```
SELECT usr.username,
       usr.user_id,
       rec.record_id,
       contrib.record_id,
       contrib.contributor_user_id
FROM 
(
    records rec

    INNER JOIN members usr ON rec.user_id = usr.user_id

    # this returns records as NULL
    LEFT OUTER JOIN contributions contrib ON rec.record_id = contrib.record_id AND contrib.contributor_user_id = usr.user_id

    # this works, but I need the username to be displayed too
    LEFT OUTER JOIN contributions contrib ON rec.record_id = contrib.record_id
)
WHERE rec.record_id = 1
```

Comment: I think you need to provide sample output for the given sample data, or a better explanation of what you're trying to pull..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try nesting the join for contributing users inside of the left join to contributions.

```
SELECT u.username, u.user_id, r.record_id, u2.username as ContributorName, u2.user_id as ContributorId
    FROM records r
        INNER JOIN members u
            ON r.user_id = u.user_id
        LEFT JOIN contributions c
            INNER JOIN members u2
                ON c.contributor_user_id = u2.user_id
            ON r.record_id = c.record_id
    WHERE r.record_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
      usr.username             AS record_owner
    , usr.user_id              AS record_owner_id
    , rec.record_id  
    , con.contributor_user_id  AS contributor_id
    , contributors.username    AS contributor_name
FROM 
    records rec
        INNER JOIN
    members usr
            ON rec.user_id = usr.user_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    contributions con
           ON rec.record_id = con.record_id 
        INNER JOIN
    members contributors
            ON con.contributor_user_id = contributors.user_id
WHERE
    rec.record_id = 1
```